# What is the easiest way to bind a float to a Label Text in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am familiar with MVVM and Data Bindings in Xamarin Forms. However currently in my Application I have a few float values in my ViewModel that I need to bind to a Label's Text in XAML.

Any solutions for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just cast the float value to a string and assign it to ViewModel property that maps the label text source?

Comment: SergioAMG  is right. You can simply cast the float value to string and then bind it. Do you have any difficulty bind the value? Or you can post your code so that others can test it for you.

Comment: @SergioAMG thanks, this worked fine for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work:

```c
Label Text="{Binding YourFloatValue, StringFormat='{0:D2}'}" />
```

Or in code behind:

```c
Label.Text = YourFloatValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You mention two things in your question, binding a float to a Label's Text property and binding "a few float values" to a Label's Text.

You can easily bind a float to a label with:

```
<Label Text="{Binding YourFloatProperty}" />
```

Or with StringFormat:

```
<Label Text="{Binding YourFloatProperty, StringFormat='This is the value: {0:D2}'}" />
```

If you want to bind multiple floats to a Label's Text, Currently, there's no way to do this with standard Xamarin Forms. It is listed as an [enhancement on GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4565) so it may appear in a later release.

You have a few options though.

1. Create a string property in your ViewModel that concatenates the floats together and bind that to the text of the label
2. In WPF there's [multibinding](http://ikeptwalking.com/binding-wpf-textblock-to-two-properties-using-multibinding/), which allows for this. You can use this [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Keboo/0d6e42028ea9e4256715) to add your own multibinding control to your Xamarin Forms project.

Example for #1:

```
string FloatText { get => $"This is the first float: {_float1} and here is the second{_float2}"; }
```

I would recommend option 1.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wrap a string property in viewmodel and set the value using `String.Format()` method.

I wrote a simple demo to explain it. 
Suppose there are 2 float values in your viewmodel: `float1` and `float2`, 
You can add a string property `OutputString` and set its value with: `this.OutputString = String.Format("Value1 is {0}; Value2 is {1}", Value1, Value2);`

And then bind the Label's Text to `OutputString`

The full code is like the following:

MyViewModel.cs

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        float value1;
        float value2;
        string outputString;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.Value1 = 1.1f;
            this.Value2 = 1.2f;
            this.OutputString = String.Format("Value1 is {0}; Value2 is {1}", Value1, Value2);
        }

        public float Value1
        {
            set
            {
                if (value1 != value)
                {
                    value1 = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value1"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return value1;
            }
        }

        public float Value2
        {
            set
            {
                if (value2 != value)
                {
                    value2 = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value2"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return value2;
            }
        }

        public string OutputString
        {
            set
            {
                if (outputString != value)
                {
                    outputString = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("OutputString"));
                    }
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return outputString;
            }
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="{Binding OutputString}" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```